# How to write this css code in React-Native

Tags: css, react-native

Ho to write this CSS code in React-Native because I didn't know how to write `:before` and `:after` in react native and marginRadius with four value given error please help me

```
div {
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div:after, 
div:before {
  content:'';
  background:white;
  position:absolute;
  top:-10px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  border-radius:0 0 50% 50%;
}
div:after {
  top:auto;
  bottom:-10px;
  border-radius:50% 50% 0 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no `div` concept in React Native. There is no pseudo class element support in React Native now. Read [here](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet/issues/46). For Applying the `borderRadius` property try like the below-given code.

```
<View style={styles.container}></View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: 500,
        height: 200,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        zIndex: 100,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 100,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 100,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
        borderTopRightRadius: 0,
    }
});
```

**Update:** As the OP updated the question, the answer is updated.A sample demo here https://codesandbox.io/s/61qxm7mqo3

Comment: yeah i know there is no div in react-native but your given css code is not make such design as i have given

Comment: I want to make inner curved  something like this Visit on above link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623777/curve-inside-image-with-css

Comment: @HunnainPasha Your question didn't cover any design. You asked about pseudo elements and border-radius. I hope that is covered in my answer

Comment: Aravind please help me i want to create inner curved deign in react-native please help me

Comment: @HunnainPasha Check out this link https://codedaily.io/tutorials/22/The-Shapes-of-React-Native

Comment: Aravind it is not inner curved. Aravind please go through this image i want to create this design https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uk3H.png

Comment: @HunnainPasha : here is the updated one https://codesandbox.io/s/61qxm7mqo3

Answer (score 0):

You could use this package [styled-component](https://www.styled-components.com/) as follows

```
const Container = styled.div`
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

    &:after, before 
      content: '';
      background: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: -10px;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 20px;
      border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;

`
```

Then use this as component

```
render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            // Other components
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi Munkh i have install styled package and use your code in react-native but there was error come